# All series on a given axis must be of the same data type google charts

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

help, i have this code but no work when i want add color for bars charts

error: All series on a given axis must be of the same data type.

```
    $conexion=new ConexionMySQL;
    $exgetChartDelitos =$conexion->Query("SELECT delito, COUNT(*)repes from geo_nsn group by delito having count(*)>1");
    $numeroFilas = mysql_num_rows($exgetChartDelitos);
    $datos[0] = array('Delito','Cantidad', '{ role: "style" }');



    for ($i=1; $i<($numeroFilas+1); $i++)
{
    $datos[$i] = array(mysql_result($exgetChartDelitos, $i-1, "delito"),
    (int) mysql_result($exgetChartDelitos, $i-1, "repes"), "silver");
}

   echo (json_encode($datos));
```

if remove "role style" column the codes work

Comment: @WhiteHat: I don't see the reason to include the [tag:google-visualization] here either :)

Comment: the question has to do with creating a style column role for google-visualization data table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the column role object is not being created properly

try it like this...

```
$datos[0] = array('Delito','Cantidad',array('role' => "style"));
```